# Execute AsyncTask loop after previous one

Tags: android, timer

I want to check unread messages after 30 seconds of previous check, means when the first check (`AsyncTask`) is complete and I have the result then I want to wait 30 seconds, then I want to check for unread messages again and so on. Here is my code:

```
    TimerTask timerTask = new CheckUnreadMessages(menuItem);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, Constants.CHECK_UNREAD_COUNT_INTERVAL);
```

Here is my `TimerTask`:

```
class CheckUnreadMessages extends TimerTask{
    MenuItem menuItem;

    public CheckUnreadMessages(MenuItem menuItem) {
        this.menuItem = menuItem;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i("PrivateHome", "Checking for unread message...");
        new CheckUnreadMessagesTask(menuItem, PrivateHome.this).execute(LocalDBSP.init().getID(PrivateHome.this));
    }
}
```

Here goes my `AsyncTask`:

```
public class CheckUnreadMessagesTask extends AsyncTask <String, String, Boolean> {
    Activity activity;
    JSONObject result;
    MenuItem menuItem;

    public CheckUnreadMessagesTask(MenuItem menuItem, Activity activity){
        this.menuItem = menuItem;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            //now update to server
            result = getResponse(URLManager.getUnreadCount(params[0]));
            return JSONHelper.isResultOK(result);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean resultOK) {
        super.onPostExecute(resultOK);

        if(resultOK){
            try {
                String count = result.getString(JSONKeys.RESULT);
                menuItem.setTitle(Constants.NAV_SEE_MESSAGES_TITLE+" ("+count+")");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it's being executed for the first time only, it's not repeating.

Comment: There is relevant code missing. What does `CheckUnreadMessagesTask.execute()` do? This part actually needs to re-schedule itself in a timer, otherwise nothing will execute this part. Also, you should share a Timer and not create a new one every time.

Comment: Updated my question, please tell me what should I do.

Comment: there is nothing in your code that suggests your task should be repeating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are not re-scheduling the `CheckUnreadMessages`, so it gets executed only once, and therefore it triggers the `CheckUnreadMessagesTask` only once.

One solution is to use `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()` instead, but this has a fixed rate and may not be what you want (often it is, though).

If you want to have the next check running 30s after the last task executed, you need to do rescheduling in `CheckUnreadMessagesTask` instead:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean resultOK) {
    super.onPostExecute(resultOK);
    TimerTask timerTask = new CheckUnreadMessages(menuItem);
    timer.schedule(timerTask, Constants.CHECK_UNREAD_COUNT_INTERVAL);
    // ...
}
```

You'll need to pass a reference to the timer to the tasks, though. I'd avoid re-creating a new timer every time, but you could do that.

Additionally, I find the name confusing, since both look similar, at least name `CheckUnreadMessages` as `CheckUnreadMessagesTimerTask` so that it is more obvious which is which.

Comment: Will recursively calling AsyncTask abuse memory? If it is, how can I avoid re-creating a new timer every time?

Comment: You need to schedule a new instance of the tasks, tasks cannot be reused.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use a AsyncTask to do this, they have a lot of problems with activity lifecycle.

You should use a periodic service or use the AlarmManager. Even a Java Thread with a while true with a sleep of 30 seconds is more safe than an async task.